# Google Analytics for separate multiple domains

Tags: google-analytics

We have over 150 separate websites that we have built for clients. In the past we were able to get Google tracking code and add it to the domain, set up a report which was emailed to each client automatically each month.

It doesn't seem to be that easy anymore - and getting info from Google is a nightmare.
I think that each 'Google account' can only hold 50 websites- anyone know any different or can anyone advise on the best way to offer simple tracking for our clients websites?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it seem more fit to add the domain to the clients email address than adding it to your own? Or create a new account for them? Thay way they have total control of it if they wish.

Otherwise, to answer your question: The best way to keep it the way you set it up is probably just to have multiple accounts. Add the extension 1, 2, 3 etc. or something.